# Iterating over an numpy.ndarray along an axis

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Suppose I have a 3D array `arr`. I want to iterate over `arr` in such a way that each iteration yields a vector along `z-axis`. This can be done but the  solution is not generalized. If the `arr.shape` and the axis along which the vectors have to be obtained are not known or variable then there seems no straight forward way to do this. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

```
for line in np.nditer(arr, axis=2):
    # Perform operation on line


arr = array(
      [[[2, 2, 8, 8],
        [6, 2, 1, 5],
        [4, 5, 1, 4]],

       [[7, 4, 7, 4],
        [0, 0, 3, 3],
        [7, 6, 8, 0]]]
)
```

Expected output:

```
[2 2 8 8]
[6 2 1 5]
[4 5 1 4]
[7 4 7 4]
[0 0 3 3]
[7 6 8 0]
```

Comment: Don't try to use `nditer`.  It isn't easy to use, and doesn't have  any speed advantages.

Comment: Aren't you trying to iterate over everything except that axis?  Have you looked at `apply_along_axis`?

Comment: You could use `moveaxis` to move the desired axis to the end, and reshape to flatten the other axes.  Then it's a straight forward iteration.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` serves my purpose nicely. 'moveaxis` is also good alternative. Thank you @hpaulj.

Answer (score 1):

In `numpy` arrays the `shape` provides you information about `# dimensions` and `# elements` in each of the dimensions. with your code we get,

```
print(arr.shape)
# (2,3,4)
# 3-D array
#   along x-axis = 2 elements each
#   along y-axis = 3 elements each
#   along z-axis = 4 elements each
```

So, If i want to look at elements along `z-axis` for all `x-axis` and `y-axis` it will look like

```
for xid in range(arr.shape[0]):     # for each x-axis
    for yid in range(arr.shape[1]): # for each y-axis
        print(arr[xid, yid, :])     # All elements in z-axis
```

Comment: This is fine. But, the problem is the axis (in this case `z`) is not pre-known (e. g. User input). In that case how to generalize this code?

Answer (score -1):

Writing the suggestions of [@hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) into an answer.

moveaxis seems to be right answer. However apply_along_axis is intuitive and also very easy to use.